# MVC 6 - can't find "Copy Local" Property of a Reference in vs 2015 beta7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Ive been trying set reference 'copy to local' property but its not available

[image: Visual Studio 2015 snapshot]

Comment: What is the parent node? Doesn't seem to be `References`?